# Sorting Google Spreadsheet on edit

Tags: sorting, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am searching for a way to sort my spreadsheet. I have looked around and found the "on edit" function but I am not entirely sure on how to use it. And how does it work with the runtime of only 5 minutes for google scripts, does a cellchange act as a trigger?
I found the following code:

```
function AutoSortOnEdit() {
  var sheetNames = ["testsheet456", "testsheet457", "testsheet458"];

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  sheetNames.forEach(function(name) {
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var range = sheet.getRange(5, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
  });
```

Personally i would use this slightly modified version:

```
function AutoSortOnEdit() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("...").getSheetByName("...");
    var range = sheet.getRange(5, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());
    range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
  });
```

Now I want to sort the sheet in alphabetical order sorted by the first row.
My questions are:

- Does "ascending" mean that it sorts in alphabetical order?
- Where do empty cells land(they should be at the end obviously)?
- Does it gets triggered on every change? Can i manipulate to only sort it when Column A gets edited?

Regards Jonny

Edit: In the end i went with my slighlty modified version since onEdit was after all not fitting in the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ascending is alphabetical. This code looks for only a change in the sheet named Sheet1 and only column A. The function must be named OnEdit (not AutoSortOnEdit).

```
function onEdit()
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName= sheet.getSheetName();
  if(sheetName=="Sheet1"){ //sheet to run on edit
  var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A"+lr);//apply on edit to
  var rangeRowStart = range.getRow();
  var rangeRowEnd = rangeRowStart + range.getHeight()-1;
  var rangeColStart = range.getColumn();
  var rangeColEnd = rangeColStart + range.getWidth()-1;
  if (editRow >= rangeRowStart && editRow <= rangeRowEnd 
      && editCol >= rangeColStart && editCol <= rangeColEnd)
  {
  var range = sheet.getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn());//Assumes header row
    range.sort({column: 1, ascending: true});
 }}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple event triggers are limited to a 30 second execution time.

[onEdit() events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#onedit) must be named simply onEdit() or onEdit(event)

onEdit can take a variable that represents the [event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change) that triggered it, that among other things, includes the range that was edited.

Sheet has it's own [sort()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#sortcolumnposition-ascending). If you are trying to sort the entire sheet it is simpler to use that.

```
function onEdit(event){
  if(event.range.getSheet().getName() == "Sheet1" && event.range.getColumn() == 1){//checks to see if the edited range was both on Sheet1 and column 1 (A)
    event.range.getSheet().sort(1,true); //sort by first column
   // event.range.getSheet().sort(1,false); //decending
  }
}
```

multiple sheets can watched by expanding the conditionals, or aditional if statements.